# What's the relationship between Value and Module in LLVM?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I try to implement a toy programminng language with LLVM as its backend. I have 2 questions about LLVM Value and Module:

1. Is it a best practice to manage all `llvm::Value`s into a `llvm::Module` ?
2. If so, how to manage the Values ?

Comment: A module is the thing that provides memory for the values that require that (global variables and functions) and also a namespace for the values that have global names.

Comment: @arnt, I create a lot of LLVM Value based on LLVM Conntext (which is based on LLVM Module), finally I use `llvmModule->print(llvm::outs(), nullptr)`, but it print only `source_filename = 'xxx'`, no function or global variable

Comment: @arnt, is there any way to print all of the LLVM Value related to the Module with one method ?

Comment: The [context](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1LLVMContext.html) is not a [Module](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Module.html). The context owns the constants that have no runtime memory (such as 1 and 2) and the types, the module owns that which has runtime memory. Read those links.